# Understanding Nulls in Aggregation Functions

Tags: postgresql

I have the table R whice contains,

```
    b    |   c 
-------------------
1        | null     
-------------------
2        | null      
-------------------
3        | 4      
-------------------
3        | 5
```

And I'm applying on it this query :

```
SELECT count(*), count(c), min(c), sum(c)
FROM  (SELECT c 
       FROM R
       WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL
       GROUP BY c)
```

Why the output will be `1,0,null,null` and not `3,2,4,9` ?

Isnt the inner query should return null,4,5 as the c row ?

I know that `count(*)` counts all rows and `count(c)` will avoid the null values.
Also `min()` and `sum()` avoiding null values.

Why this is the result ?

Comment: what is this `WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL`?

Comment: i think this should give every row, because any value is null of !=null

Comment: There is no meaning to this query i just want to understand why the return value are 1,0,null,null

Comment: well you are right, but even w/o the WHERE this should be the result and i cant undetstand why,
*edit*: w/o the WHERE the result is 3,2,4,9 so i guess im missing something even more basic

Comment: You are mixing several different misunderstandings into a single question, which isn't helpful. Start without subquery, then without `WHERE` in the subquery ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this:

```
with R(    b    ,   c ) as (
    select 1        , null::int union all  
    select 2        , null::int union all   
    select 3        , 4    union all
    select 3        , 5  
)
SELECT c 
       FROM R
       WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL;
```

it will give you:

```
null
null
```

why? because **`c<>null` is always null** and so, non null values won't be fetched. You wanna use `c is not null` to check if a col is not null. though ,here it wouldn't make much sense anyway.

further, group by on it:

```
SELECT c 
   FROM R
   WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL
   GROUP BY c;
```

produces single null

```
null
```

then on which final aggregates will produces:

```
SELECT count(*), count(c), min(c), sum(c)
FROM  (SELECT c 
   FROM R
   WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL
   GROUP BY c) t

1,0,null,null
```

Use this:

```
with R(    b    ,   c ) as (
    select 1        , null::int union all  
    select 2        , null::int union all   
    select 3        , 4    union all
    select 3        , 5  
)
SELECT count(*), count(c), min(c), sum(c)
FROM  (SELECT c 
       FROM R
       GROUP BY c) t
```

produces:

```
count   count   min sum
3       2       4   9
```

[DEMO for you](http://rextester.com/DUFKN12531)

Answer (score 0):

If you executes your subquery:

```
SELECT c 
       FROM R
       WHERE c IS NULL or c <> NULL
       GROUP BY c;
```

It returns NULL

Then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NULL;
```

Returs the same as `SELECT COUNT(*)` = 1

```
SELECT COUNT(C)
```

Returns the same as `SELECT COUNT(NULL)` = 0

And

```
MIN(NULL), SUM(NULL) = NULL
```

If redefines your query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(C), MIN(C), SUM(C)
FROM
    (SELECT c
    FROM R
    WHERE c IS NULL or c IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY c) A;
```

The result is:

```
count | count | min | sum
  3       2      3     7
```

Due the subquery returns:

```
 C
----
NULL
 4
 3
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please explian why the inner query return null ?
isnt every row could be null in c or !=null in c ?